# ELMAH setup - The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace System

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have downloaded the latest ELMAH and copied the sample app's Web.Config settings to my ASP.NET 3.5 Web.Config.

I have made sure to reference the 3.5 release version of the DLL, but I am still getting the above error (as per the title of this post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the reference then confirm you have an entry in your assemblies dictionary from the web.config that has the dll that contains Linq. For example:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, ...
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ dll is not automatically added to a web project, you have to add it manually in the solution explorer to the project references.